# Why Html is not being appended to the div in this case

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add html to the existing div dynamically

But why this is not being appeneded

This is my program

http://jsfiddle.net/y3aragzc/5/

```
<div class="cascade" id="T1">
</div>    

var datafort1 = ["One" , "Two" , "Three" , "Four" , "Five"];

var html = '<div>\
    <div class="lt_div">\
    <select id="T1Select" tabindex="1" style="width:100%;">';
  for (var i = 0; i < datafort1.length; i++) {
        var val = datafort1[i];
        if (val) {
            html += '<option value="' + datafort1[i] + '">' + datafort1[i] + '</option>';
        }
    }
html +=
        '</select>\
    </div>\
    <div class="row-fluid">\
    <div class="col9 pull-left" id="displayt11">\
    </div>\
    </div>\
    </div>';


 var plus = '<span>Hii</span>';

$("#displayt11").append(plus);

    $("#T1").append(html);


// For Change in T1
$(document).on('change', '#T1Select', function(event) {



});
```

Could anybody please help me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run `$("#displayt11").append(plus);` after `$("#T1").append(html);` since the element for `$("#displayt11")` is not even in dom

Comment: He is right, @Preethi Jain should run `$("#T1").append(html);` first and then `$("#displayt11").append(plus);` check [http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/y3aragzc/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("#T1").append(html);
```

before this:

```
$("#displayt11").append(plus);
```